# privileged mode in docker compose in a swarm

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am using `docker-compose.yml` to deploy services in a docker swarm which has cluster of raspberry pis. My services require access to the raspberry pi GPIO and needs privileged mode. I am using docker version 18.02 with docker-compose version 3.6. When I deploy the stack, I receive the following message and the services do not get deployed: "`Ignoring unsupported options: privileged`". Any tips? Below is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.6'     

networks:
    swarm_network:
        driver: overlay


services:
    service1:
        image: localrepo/img1:v0.1
        privileged: true
        deploy:
            mode: replicated
            replicas: 1
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - node.hostname == home-desktop

        ports:
            - published: 8000
              target: 8000
              mode: host

        networks:
            swarm_network:

    service2:
        image: localrepo/img1:v0.1 
        privileged: true
        deploy:
            mode: replicated
            replicas: 1

        ports:
            - published: 7000
              target: 7000
              mode: host

        networks:
            swarm_network:

    nodeViewer:
      image: alexellis2/visualizer-arm:latest
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
      volumes:
        - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      deploy:
        placement:
          constraints: [node.role == manager]
      networks:
        - swarm_network
```

Answer (score 6):

Thats because privileged is not supported in docker swarm. I had a similar docker compose running in privileged mode but while using it to docker swarm I removed them and was working well.

That not exactly an error .For example if you use something like **links or depends_on** . You get similar warning message. These are just the warnings not errors.

This is how you actually check the error logs if there is any

```
docker service ls (to check running service) 

docker service logs servicename
```

Comment: I know it is not an error message. It is just privileged mode isn't supported in docker swarm. But I want to deploy my services over a cluster of devices. Can I use docker compose to do that without the swarm mode?? Meaning that, is it possible to orchestrate services over cluster of nodes with just docker compose?

Comment: I don't think that is possible only with docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

Whole feature is implemented and works as far I can see so who ever want to test it can do it by downloading latest nightly build of Docker engine (dockerd) from https://master.dockerproject.org and the custom build version of Docker CLI from https://github.com/olljanat/cli/releases/tag/beta1
You can also find usage examples for CLI from docker/cli#2199 and for Stack from docker/cli#1940 If you find bugs from those please leave comment to correct PR. Also notice that syntax might still change during review.

Source: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25885#issuecomment-557790402

I've personally tested it and it works like a charm. thanks to the [author](https://github.com/olljanat).